# Inexpensive NFC reader for (Windows & Linux) login

Tags: nfc

I see cheap NFC rings [on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/NFC-Smart-Wearable-Ring-New-Technology-For-Windows-IOS-Android-Mobile-Phone-W2/292363998296) and elsewhere. I was wondering if there is a very cheap NFC reader which I could use to detect such a ring and use it as an HID keyboard (probably over USB) to input my Windows, and hopefully Linux, password.

[image]

Comment: An HDMI keyboard? Do you mean USB, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, HDMI keyboards don't exist. Or if they do, they're incredibly niche. Did you mean HID - Human Interface Device?

Comment: Lolx - never post late at night: Yup - HID (question corrected)

Comment: There's plenty in the $10 to $15 range on Ali Express - for Raspberry Pi & Arduino.  Maybe I can adapt one of those, or have the Pi communicate with teh PC ...